# How to launch NSTask as root, modern approach?

Tags: macos, cocoa

guys.

I need some help to figure out how to give some privilege to my program. I'm writing a small utility to wrap in GUI **openVPN**. It's actually just a bash script I launch as a **NSTask**: `sudo  openvpn --config clientUDP.conf`. 
After a couple of hours of searching on the internet, I figured I should use an *authorization services tasks* and write a **PrivilegedHelper**. It's quite awkward for me, guys (basically I'm iOs developer and it's my first try mini mac os app).

My question is - is there any modern tutorial to figure out how to write a PrivilegedHelper (in swift or objc) to launch my NSTask with root rights?

P.S. I've downloaded SMJobBless example and launched it. But I didn't find in it any kind of inter-process communication, and I can't figure out how to launch my Process as root.

I really need your advice and rely on your experience.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the "lifecycle" of your app you will need to get authorization from an admin user. You could package the openvpn command as a launchd job installed in /Library/LaunchDaemons, which would require admin authorization to install. Look at `launchd.plist(5)` and then create a plist starting like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.startopenvpn</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/path/to/openvpn</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>--config</string>
        <string>clientUDP.conf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You will want to add a launch trigger (mach message or some other trigger) to launch the job. More info can be found at [Daemons and Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html)

You could use the Authorization APIs and put up a GUI to get the authorization from the admin at runtime. Haven't used this method so I don't have any direct advice. [Authorization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011200-CH201-TPXREF101)